# ng2-chart line chart delete number

Tags: angular, chart.js, linechart, ng2-charts

The line chart works perfectly but each data, instead of being a dot on the line like in the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/LineChart), it's the value. I would like to have the dots

[Chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFtm3.png)

My code:

```js
  public lineChartOptions: (ChartOptions) = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{}],
      yAxes: [
        {id: 'y-axis-0',position: 'left'},
        {
          id: 'y-axis-1',
          position: 'right',
          gridLines: {
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
          },
          ticks: {
            fontColor: 'red',
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  };
  public lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)',
      borderColor: 'red',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ];
    public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
  ];
    public lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
```

```html
        <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
          [datasets]="lineChartData"
          [labels]="lineChartLabels"
          [options]="lineChartOptions"
          [colors]="lineChartColors"
          [legend]="true"
          chartType="line"
          [plugins]="chartPlugins"></canvas>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to remove the plugins, because that is probably what is causing it.

Comment: @LeeLenalee I tried, but the values are still there. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: use data display equal to false.
plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        align: 'center',
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: false,
      },
    },